# How can I get notified when NSViewController instance is loaded / unloaded

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit, nsviewcontroller

On iOS, there are viewDidAppear / viewDidDisappear methods. They are also being added to Yosemite (see https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKit/#10_10ViewController).

Question: how can I detect when my view is appearing / disappearing pre-OS X 10.10?

Comment: Just an idea: perhaps there's some room for overriding `addSubview:` etc. in a subclass...? I'm guessing the `superview` property is readonly, so intercepting `setSuperview:` is not possible...

Answer (score -1):

You can use [**loadView**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSViewController_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html#jumpTo_7)

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];

}
```

I don't know your goal but if you really needed it. There was `viewDidUnload` and `viewWillUnload` but Apple deprecated them and warned people that they are being misused.

The cost of releasing objects when the view unload is not expensive so they just got rid of it.

Comment: `loadView` can address the activation bit. Any ideas for deactivation?

Comment: It seems the `viewDidUnload` was available on iOS, as a quick Google search isn't showing anything specifically for OS X.

Comment: loadView is for controllers that load their view programmatically (i.e., not from a nib or storyboard). viewDidAppear and viewDidDissappear are what you want.

Comment: @wcochran so you  downvote me instead of pozting your answer

Answer (score -1):

The only way I can see pre-Yosemite systems using something similar to `viewDidDisappear` is to subclass `NSView` and overriding `viewDidHide` to call a delegate class.

Or you could do some method swizzling on the `NSView` class on pre-Yosemite systems.